# How to use a listview having text on every row with different language?

Tags: android, android-listview, multiple-languages

I know that some applications using this in a hard-coded way to choose language and after that Locale is used to select language for multiple language support.

Is this the right approach? Or am I able to use rows with different language string in custom adapter list view?

Comment: why peoples are giving down vote for this...

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible with web services. u can get data in different language with api and display that. if web service present.
also u can use database.and store in array list and display in adpter